# Repeating Events

Tags: php

For my current project, I am creating a php script that allows our Instructors to manage their available time so students can view it. I have it up and running just fine, but I was asked to add a few things to it. Basically, when instructors go to add their time, they need to be able to "repeat this every Monday,Tues,Wed etc. for so many times" My current code to do this is below:

```
$cid = $_SESSION['CID'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$btime = $_POST['btime'];
$etime = $_POST['etime'];
$rep_mon = $_POST['repeat_day_mon'];
$rep_tues = $_POST['repeat_day_tues'];
$rep_wed = $_POST['repeat_day_wed'];
$rep_thur = $_POST['repeat_day_thur'];
$rep_fri = $_POST['repeat_day_fri'];
$rep_sat = $_POST['repeat_day_sat'];
$rep_sun = $_POST['repeat_day_sun'];
$xrep_day = $_POST['xrepeat_day']; //How many times they want to repeat it
$current_month = date("n");
$tm = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
$day_name = date("D",$tm);

if($rep_mon == '1')
{
    if($day_name == 'Mon')
    {
        $counter = 0;
        $day1 = $day;

        while($counter <= $xrep_day)
        {
            $q1 = sprintf("INSERT INTO `INS_TIME`(cid, month, day, year, btime, etime)VALUES('%s', '%s','%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", 
                          mysql_real_escape_string($cid, $con), 
                          mysql_real_escape_string($month, $con), 
                          mysql_real_escape_string($day1, $con),
                          mysql_real_escape_string($year, $con),
                          mysql_real_escape_string($btime, $con),
                          mysql_real_escape_string($etime, $con));                
            mysql_query($q1, $con) or die("There was an error with the query:" . mysql_error()); 
            $counter++;
            $day1 += 7;
        }
    }

    if($day_name == 'Tue')
    {
        $counter = 0;
        $day1 = $day;
        while($counter <= $xrep_day)
        {
            $q1 = sprintf("INSERT INTO `INS_TIME`(cid, month, day, year, btime, etime)VALUES('%s', '%s','%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", 
                          mysql_real_escape_string($cid, $con), 
                          mysql_real_escape_string($month, $con), 
                          mysql_real_escape_string($day1, $con),
                          mysql_real_escape_string($year, $con),
                          mysql_real_escape_string($btime, $con),
                          mysql_real_escape_string($etime, $con));                
            mysql_query($q1, $con) or die("There was an error with the query:" . mysql_error()); 
            $counter++;
            $day1 += 6;

            if($counter >=2)
            {
                $day1++;
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
```

It continues with more ifs but I didnt want to paste it all in as it is over 1000 lines long. If you need the whole code I can easily get it too you.

We have noticed that sometimes it doesnt work right and will reapeat things more than once, or not at all. I would also like to accomplish the task with shorter code and less ifs.

if you can think of a better way to do this I would be most appreciative!

Thanks!

:::::EDIT:::::
New Code that doesnt want to work:

```
$this_sunday = time() - (date("w") * 86400); // this will give you Sunday
$monday = $this_sunday + 1 * 86400; // 86400 = seconds in a day
$tuesday = $this_sunday + 2 * 86400; // 86400 = seconds in a day
$wednesday = $this_sunday + 3 * 86400; // 86400 = seconds in a day
$thursday = $this_sunday + 4 * 86400; // 86400 = seconds in a day
$friday = $this_sunday + 5 * 86400; // 86400 = seconds in a day
$saturday = $this_sunday + 6 * 86400; // 86400 = seconds in a day
$sunday= $this_sunday + 7 * 86400; // 86400 = seconds in a day
$start_time = mktime($hour, $minute, 0, $month, $day, $year); 

//FUNCTION TO DO THE ACTUAL REPEATING
function repeat($start_time, $duration, $repeat) 
{
    $week = 604800; // 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 (1 week in seconds)

    for ($i=0; $i<$repeat; ++$i, $start_time += $week) 
    {
        $date = date("Y-m-d", $start_time);
        $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO STAT_INS_AVAIL(CID,DATE,DURATION)VALUES('%s','%s','%s')",$cid,$date,$duration);
    }
}
//REPEAT ON MONDAYS
if($rep_mon == '1')
{
repeat($monday, $duration, $xrep_day);
}
//REPEAT ON TUESDAYS
if($rep_tues == '1')
{
repeat($tuesday, $duration, $xrep_day);
}//REPEAT ON WEDBNESDAYS
if($rep_wed == '1')
{
repeat($wednesday, $duration, $xrep_day);
}//REPEAT ON THURSDAYS
if($rep_thur == '1')
{
repeat($thursday, $duration, $xrep_day);
}//REPEAT ON FRIDAYS
if($rep_fri == '1')
{
repeat($friday, $duration, $xrep_day);
}//REPEAT ON SATURDAYSS
if($rep_sat == '1')
{
repeat($saturday, $duration, $xrep_day);
}//REPEAT ON SUNDAYS
if($rep_sun == '1')
{
repeat($sunday, $duration, 4);
}
//Go through this is they do not want to repeat AT ALL
if(!$rep_mon || !$rep_tues || !$rep_wed || !$rep_thur || !$rep_fri || !$rep_sat || !$rep_sun)
{
$date = date("Y-m-d G:i:s", $start_time);
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO STAT_INS_AVAIL(CID,DATE,DURATION)VALUES('%s','%s','%s')",$cid,$date,$duration);
mysql_query($sql,$con);
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you have separate fields for year, month, day and two times, I assume begin and end? Why not just use datetime + int for duration in minutes?

Comment: Need some more code or at least some information on what the variables $rep_mon , $day_name, $xrep_day are and where they come from? What about the inputs to the SQL, $cid , $month. Are they user input coming in a $_POST or $_GET ?

Comment: It might be easier to calculate the start date (mktime) and the end date, do an insert, and then add 604800 (number of seconds in a week) to get the start time of the next week's event etc until you go past the end date.

Comment: sorry, i updated the post with that info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
function repeat($start_time, $duration, $repeat) {

    $week = 604800; // 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 (1 week in seconds)

    for ($i=0; $i<$repeat; ++$i, $start_time += $week) {
        $date = date("Y-m-d", $start_time);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ... $date, $duration ...";
    }
}

$start = mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year); 
// some logic to figure out start times by dates of the week
// ...

repeat($monday, 100, 4);
repeat($tuesday, 100, 4);
```

And of course I would use a single `DATETIME` field to store datetimes, and an `INTEGER` to store the duration in minutes (or whatever is more convenient).

> **EDIT**: You could put the scheduling part in a function and call it with different parameters, but you still need logic to figure out the correct start times.

---

To figure out the start of the week, you can use something like:

```
$this_sunday = time() - (date("w") * 86400); // this will give you Sunday

$tuesday = $this_sunday + 2 * 86400; // 86400 = seconds in a day
$friday = $this_sunday + 5 * 86400; // 86400 = seconds in a day
```

Comment: So say if they selected to repeat 3 times every Wed, and they date they put in is a Mon, this will add it every Wed 3 times and once on that Monday?

Comment: @Sam This will repeat 3 times from whatever is on `$start_time`. It will be your job to figure out the correct `$start_time` for each day of the week.

Comment: Ok I see so I just need to write some logic that will look at the date they put in, and look at the day they want to repeat it on and make the          `$start_time` the day they want to repeat it on?

Comment: Ok Thanks. Probably should have made it clearer at the beginning, but that logic to get the start times was what I really wanted help on.

Comment: So for some reason the code doesnt seem to actually repeat.... Take a look at the question for the new code I am using. Why wont it work?

Comment: @Sam It doesn't seem like you are executing any queries in the function `repeat()`